# How to run a phantomjs test script which takes multiple screenshots and involves click events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, click, phantomjs, screenshot

Following problem - for later visual regression testing I'd like to take screenshots of a website which involves multiple states (mostly shown or hidden Divs triggered by click events).

I'm using phantomjs version 2.1.1 as node module.

Here is the code which is not exactly the code I use but an easy to reproduce example. The problems that occure in my script are the same in this example.

Here is the code:

**Testfile:**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var start_time = new Date().getTime();
console.info('beginning of script');

page.open('http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp', function() {    
    console.info('page opened: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000);

    window.setTimeout(function () {     
        page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementById('main').getBoundingClientRect(); 
        });     
        page.render('closed.png');
        console.info('first screenshot taken: '+ (new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000);

        /*
        //this did not work, element could be selected, but no click was triggered
        var a = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.querySelector('.flip');
        });     
        console.info('a.offsetLeft: '+a.offsetLeft);
        console.info('a.offsetTop: '+a.offsetTop);      
        //page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft+5, a.offsetTop+5);   
        page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft+5, a.offsetTop+5, 'left'); 
        */

        /*
        //this also didn't work
        var a = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.querySelector('.flip');
        });
        //var a = document.querySelector(".flip"); //using just this would cause this error: Typeerror 'null' is not an object but should work as stated here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11258
        a.addEventListener('click', function() { // Typeerror: undefined is not a function, a.addEventListener ...
            console.info('click on flip button');
        });
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(evt);   
        */

        //http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html
        // this runs without an error but within the opened.png screenshot the box is still closed
        page.injectJs("jquery.min.js", function(){ //the jquery file is in the testfile folder
            console.info('element.length: '+$('.flip').length);
            $('.flip').click();
            console.info('click triggered: '+ (new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000);
        });

        //console.info('click triggered: '+ (new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000);  
        window.setTimeout(function () {             
            page.render('opened.png');  
            console.info('second screenshot taken: '+ (new Date().getTime() - start_time)/1000);    
            phantom.exit();
        },5000);
    },5000);    
});
```

The errors that occure are within the comments. Whatever I do there is an error or no error but within the Screenshots the box that should be opened is always closed.

**Console Command (using Windows prompt):**

```
phantomjs --debug=no --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any --local-to-remote-url-access=true button_test.js
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Above I was using the wrong function - it has to be `IncludeJs` instead of `InjectJs`. But I think I already tried IncludeJs in version 1.9 and it didn't work - $ was undefined in the callback. Anyway I replaced the last part with this and now it works:

```
page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js", function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        //console infos won't work here
        $('.flip').click();                 
    });
    page.render('opened.png');
});

window.setTimeout(function () {             
    phantom.exit();
},5000);
```